# could not execute query. Программа не видит таблицы

Tags: java, hibernate

Я проблему свою уже описывал но сейчас сделаю это более конкретно. Программа стоит на сервере, работает день, каждую ночь программа падает. При перезапуска томката опять всё в норме. Утром при выводе содержимого таблицы я получил такие ошибки:

```
org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: could not execute query
    at org.hibernate.exception.ErrorCodeConverter.handledNonSpecificException(ErrorCodeConverter.java:92)
    at org.hibernate.exception.ErrorCodeConverter.convert(ErrorCodeConverter.java:80)
    at org.hibernate.exception.JDBCExceptionHelper.convert(JDBCExceptionHelper.java:43)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:1518)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:1498)
    at org.hibernate.loader.hql.QueryLoader.list(QueryLoader.java:369)
    at org.hibernate.hql.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.list(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:266)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.list(SessionImpl.java:788)
    at org.hibernate.impl.QueryImpl.list(QueryImpl.java:74)
    at DAOImpl.JurnalDAOImpl.getAllJurnal(JurnalDAOImpl.java:34)
    at servlets.JurnalController.performTask(JurnalController.java:45)
    at servlets.AbstractController.doGet(AbstractController.java:14)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:936)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1004)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:310)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure

Last packet sent to the server was 50841 ms ago.
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:403)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createCommunicationsException(SQLError.java:1074)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.reuseAndReadPacket(MysqlIO.java:2874)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.reuseAndReadPacket(MysqlIO.java:2764)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3286)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:1852)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:1975)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2476)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeInternal(PreparedStatement.java:1583)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeQuery(PreparedStatement.java:1725)
    at org.hibernate.jdbc.AbstractBatcher.getResultSet(AbstractBatcher.java:118)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getResultSet(Loader.java:1197)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:366)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:206)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:1515)
    ... 26 more
Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Software caused connection abort: recv failed
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.util.ReadAheadInputStream.fill(ReadAheadInputStream.java:113)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.util.ReadAheadInputStream.readFromUnderlyingStreamIfNecessary(ReadAheadInputStream.java:160)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.util.ReadAheadInputStream.read(ReadAheadInputStream.java:188)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.readFully(MysqlIO.java:2330)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.reuseAndReadPacket(MysqlIO.java:2775)
    ... 38 more
org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: could not execute query
    at org.hibernate.exception.ErrorCodeConverter.handledNonSpecificException(ErrorCodeConverter.java:92)
    at org.hibernate.exception.ErrorCodeConverter.convert(ErrorCodeConverter.java:80)
    at org.hibernate.exception.JDBCExceptionHelper.convert(JDBCExceptionHelper.java:43)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:1518)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:1498)
    at org.hibernate.loader.hql.QueryLoader.list(QueryLoader.java:369)
    at org.hibernate.hql.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.list(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:266)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.list(SessionImpl.java:788)
    at org.hibernate.impl.QueryImpl.list(QueryImpl.java:74)
    at DAOImpl.RajonDAOImpl.getAllRajon(RajonDAOImpl.java:26)
    at servlets.JurnalController.performTask(JurnalController.java:47)
    at servlets.AbstractController.doGet(AbstractController.java:14)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:936)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1004)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:310)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLNonTransientConnectionException: No operations allowed after connection closed.Connection was implicitly closed due to underlying exception/error:


** BEGIN NESTED EXCEPTION ** 

com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException
MESSAGE: Communications link failure

Last packet sent to the server was 50841 ms ago.

STACKTRACE:

com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure

Last packet sent to the server was 50841 ms ago.
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:403)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createCommunicationsException(SQLError.java:1074)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.reuseAndReadPacket(MysqlIO.java:2874)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.reuseAndReadPacket(MysqlIO.java:2764)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3286)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:1852)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:1975)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2476)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeInternal(PreparedStatement.java:1583)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeQuery(PreparedStatement.java:1725)
    at org.hibernate.jdbc.AbstractBatcher.getResultSet(AbstractBatcher.java:118)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getResultSet(Loader.java:1197)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:366)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:206)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:1515)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:1498)
    at org.hibernate.loader.hql.QueryLoader.list(QueryLoader.java:369)
    at org.hibernate.hql.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.list(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:266)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.list(SessionImpl.java:788)
    at org.hibernate.impl.QueryImpl.list(QueryImpl.java:74)
    at DAOImpl.JurnalDAOImpl.getAllJurnal(JurnalDAOImpl.java:34)
    at servlets.JurnalController.performTask(JurnalController.java:45)
    at servlets.AbstractController.doGet(AbstractController.java:14)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:936)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1004)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:310)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Software caused connection abort: recv failed
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.util.ReadAheadInputStream.fill(ReadAheadInputStream.java:113)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.util.ReadAheadInputStream.readFromUnderlyingStreamIfNecessary(ReadAheadInputStream.java:160)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.util.ReadAheadInputStream.read(ReadAheadInputStream.java:188)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.readFully(MysqlIO.java:2330)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.reuseAndReadPacket(MysqlIO.java:2775)
    ... 38 more


** END NESTED EXCEPTION **


    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:403)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:378)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:985)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:957)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:927)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.checkClosed(ConnectionImpl.java:1102)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.prepareStatement(ConnectionImpl.java:3906)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.prepareStatement(ConnectionImpl.java:3872)
    at org.hibernate.jdbc.AbstractBatcher.getPreparedStatement(AbstractBatcher.java:379)
    at org.hibernate.jdbc.AbstractBatcher.getPreparedStatement(AbstractBatcher.java:320)
    at org.hibernate.jdbc.AbstractBatcher.prepareQueryStatement(AbstractBatcher.java:86)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.prepareQueryStatement(Loader.java:1089)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:365)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:206)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:1515)
    ... 26 more
```

Подскажите в чём может быть проблема=( И да, на серве 2 программы, написаны по одному принципу. 1 работает, а вторая падает. Заранее спасибо

Comment: Вы можете отредактировать, либо удалить [предыдущий вопрос](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/631876/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B0-%D0%BD%D0%B5-%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B4%D0%B8%D1%82-%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%86%D1%8B) чтобы не плодить дубликаты.

Comment: Сейчас попробую удалить

Comment: По всем признакам tcp-соединение было закрыто без завершения jdbc-соединения. Между программой и сервером БД есть маршрутизаторы и/или брандмауэры?

Comment: не знаю. сейчас буду спрашивать у админа. Главный вопрос, точно ли не ошибка в программе? Я не вижу по крайней мере никаких косяков. =(

Comment: Добавьте настройки подключения к БД. Скорее всего `mysql` разрывает соединение через 8 часов после последнего запроса. У Вас стоит  в url подключения к БД параметр `autoReconnect=true`?

Comment: А где прописывать autoReconnect?@MrFylypenko

Comment: <property name="connection.url">
   jdbc:mysql://192.168.1.3/jurnalplity
  </property>
  <property name="connection.username">
   medinsky
  </property>
  <property name="connection.password">
   0749
  </property>
  <property name="connection.driver_class">
   com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
  </property>
  <property name="dialect">
   org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
  </property>
  <property name="show_sql">
   true
  </property>
  <property name="connection.pool_size">
   1
  </property>
  <property name="current_session_context_class">
   thread
  </property>@MrFylypenko

Comment: Есть касперский, но 2 программу он не блочит@Sergey Gornostaev

Comment: Пусть админ проверит ещё параметры wait_timeout, interactive_timeout и connect_timeout сервера MySQL.

Comment: От отвалился с конторы на время. Надо самому. Не подскажете как мне эти параметры посмотреть? @Sergey Gornostaev

Comment: @NightWolf настройка должна выглядеть так: `<property name="connection.url"> jdbc:mysql://192.168.1.3/jurnalplity?autoReconnect=true </property>` но лучше использовать пул соединений, например c3p0

Comment: Спасибо попробую)@MrFylypenko

Comment: @MrFylypenko Ваш метод не помог(

Comment: @NightWolf попробуйте добавить пул соединений [c3p0](https://www.mkyong.com/hibernate/how-to-configure-the-c3p0-connection-pool-in-hibernate/) , только укажите Вашу версию библиотеки. У меня к тому что указано по ссылке добавлен параметр `<property name="hibernate.c3p0.preferredTestQuery" value="select 1;"/>`